# how to disable passport generate document option in civicrm in users profile

Tags: civicrm-entity, document-management

I want to disable passport generate document in CiviCRM users dashboard only. Can you please help me how I can do it this option is not available in permissions and display preferences also.

[image]

this is my Accounting person's dashboard but I want he could'nt be able to generate passport document so I want to disable this.

Comment: Do you have a custom Extension that is providing this? Because this is not a default / out-of-the-box feature - see for example https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=204

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the [Access CiviOffice permission](https://docs.civicrm.org/civioffice/en/latest/installation/#basic-configuration-steps), assuming they don't need to use CiviOffice otherwise.

Comment: an extension that generates passports?? must be in hot demand!

Comment: Can you please help me how I can restrict access of Passport/Generate Documents in my sales member profile because I don't want to show this field.

Comment: You need to remove the permission from their user account in your CMS.